# Feed reader working on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

Ok I got the code for a feed parser from the ibm website. It works perfectly on the emulator,however on the phone it just stops at one point.

The code is:

```
package org.developerworks.android;
import java.util.List;

public interface FeedParser {
    List<Message> parse();
}





public abstract class BaseFeedParser implements FeedParser {

    // names of the XML tags
    static final String PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
    static final  String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final  String LINK = "link";
    static final  String TITLE = "title";
    static final  String ITEM = "item";

    final URL feedUrl;

    protected BaseFeedParser(String feedUrl){
        try {
            this.feedUrl = new URL(feedUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}






public class SaxFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

    protected SaxFeedParser(String feedUrl){
        super(feedUrl);
    }

    public List<Message> parse() {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
            parser.parse(this.getInputStream(), handler);
            return handler.getMessages();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }
}


import static org.developerworks.android.BaseFeedParser.*;

public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private List<Message> messages;
    private Message currentMessage;
    private StringBuilder builder;

    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        return this.messages;
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        if (this.currentMessage != null){
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                currentMessage.setTitle(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                currentMessage.setLink(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
                currentMessage.setDescription(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)){
                currentMessage.setDate(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
                messages.add(currentMessage);
            }
            builder.setLength(0);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
        messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
            this.currentMessage = new Message();
        }
    }
}

public class AndroidSaxFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

    public AndroidSaxFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        super(feedUrl);
    }

    public List<Message> parse() {
        final Message currentMessage = new Message();
        RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
        final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
        Element item = channel.getChild(ITEM);
        item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){
            public void end() {
                messages.add(currentMessage.copy());
            }
        });
        item.getChild(TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setTitle(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild(LINK).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setLink(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild(DESCRIPTION).setEndTextElementListener(new 
EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setDescription(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild(PUB_DATE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setDate(body);
            }
        });
        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, 
root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}





public class XmlPullFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {
    public XmlPullFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        super(feedUrl);
    }
    public List<Message> parse() {
        List<Message> messages = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        try {
            // auto-detect the encoding from the stream
            parser.setInput(this.getInputStream(), null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            Message currentMessage = null;
            boolean done = false;
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done){
                String name = null;
                switch (eventType){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
                            currentMessage = new Message();
                        } else if (currentMessage != null){
                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                                currentMessage.setLink(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
                                currentMessage.setDescription(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)){
                                currentMessage.setDate(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                                currentMessage.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                            }    
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM) && 
currentMessage != null){
                            messages.add(currentMessage);
                        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CHANNEL)){
                            done = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}



private String writeXml(List<Message> messages){
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", "messages");
        serializer.attribute("", "number", String.valueOf(messages.size()));
        for (Message msg: messages){
            serializer.startTag("", "message");
            serializer.attribute("", "date", msg.getDate());
            serializer.startTag("", "title");
            serializer.text(msg.getTitle());
            serializer.endTag("", "title");
            serializer.startTag("", "url");
            serializer.text(msg.getLink().toExternalForm());
            serializer.endTag("", "url");
            serializer.startTag("", "body");
            serializer.text(msg.getDescription());
            serializer.endTag("", "body");
            serializer.endTag("", "message");
        }
        serializer.endTag("", "messages");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
}
```

If you don't understand the code,it's fully explained here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

My problem on the phone starts on the MessageList.java like this:
It first calls: loadFeed(ParserType.ANDROID_SAX);

Then the function:

```
private void loadFeed(ParserType type){
        try{
            Log.i("AndroidNews", "ParserType="+type.name());
            FeedParser parser = FeedParserFactory.getParser(type);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            messages = parser.parse();
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            Log.i("AndroidNews", "Parser duration=" + duration);
            String xml = writeXml();
            Log.i("AndroidNews", xml);
            List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            for (Message msg : messages){
                titles.add(msg.getTitle());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titles);
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
    }
```

At the messages = parser.parse(); line the code just stops,no error and the screen remains black on my phone.

All the code was designed for android 1.5! My phone and the emulator have android 2.3.3!
KEEP IN MIND THAT: On the emulator the code works! On my phone it stops at the messages = parser.parse(); line.

Can someone give me a solution or something?

Comment: This sounds like a typical task dor debugger. Set some breakpoints to see where the code "stops".

Comment: it stops at messages = parser.parse(); on my phone,I already tested it. Before that line it works,when that line executes nothing happens,it just stops at that line... However on my emulator it works...

Comment: I'm having this issue too - hope to see an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the parsing logic in a async task.